# Malformed xml not parsing in XDocument.Parse

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Please help, I have an xml document that I want to parse with XDocument. But the xml string that I have has multiple xmlns attributes that is empty. xmlns="" and the moment I remove it it parse, But I receive this from a webservice. I tried replacing it but every which way I try it only replaces one " and I am left with an invalid xmlstring `<test xmlns=">` I tried regex, I tried the Replace function I tried every know way, and I am now stuck,

Any Suggestions?

```
string xmlString = @"
        <UserFile xmlns=""http://temuri.org"">
            <user>
                <UserName>Daniel</UserName>
                <UserSurname>Vrey</UserSurname>
                <Toys xmlns="">
                    <TToy>Toyota</TToy>
                    <TToy>Ford</TToy>
                </Toys>
            </user>
</UserFile>";

XDocument d = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

Comment: Post your code, sample xml of what you're parsing and the invalid xml etc. Without that we can't help

Comment: i will upload shortly

Comment: Not in comments, edit your question and update the C# code and xml and malformed xml also

Comment: You need to explain which result you want for a sample you post. The namespace is a part of the `XName` of an element node so if you want to remove an `xmlns=""` from the `Toys` element you basically want to change the namespace of that element and its descendants.